# Regarding CSS - Using CSS position property but it is not working

Tags: html, css

I just would like to know what am I doing wrong? I used the exact same code for positioning other images. But for some reason, It is not working now. Basically, I feel like my CSS is not working. I also trying to design links but the CSS part is not working.

Hope it makes sense. Thanks and looking forward to hearing from you guys.

HTML Part:

```
<div id = 'last-part-of-the-side-news'>
  <img id = 'apple' src = 'images/wework.jpg'>
</div>
```

CSS Part:

```
#last-part-of-the-side-news{
  float:left;
}

#apple{
  width: 230px;
  height: 140px;
  position:relative;
  bottom: 448px;
  left: 200px;
}
```

Comment: please mention what do you want to achieve and add a minimum reproducible code.

Comment: Hey taufique, It would be really helpful you provide some more details with your questions like where you want to position your image.

Comment: Did you remember to link the stylesheet in the html document?

Comment: The css is working, if you lower the values you'll see the image

Comment: *I used the exact same code for positioning other images.* -- I suspect you are using the same `id` multiple times...

Comment: If an answer helped you, then please mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image is positioned 448px above and 200px to the right of your div.
Here is a snippet to illustrate the example:

```css
#last-part-of-the-side-news{
  float:left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 448px;
}

#apple{
  background: rgba(255,0,0,0.3);
  width: 230px;
  height: 140px;
  position:relative;
  bottom: 448px;
  left: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id = 'last-part-of-the-side-news'>
  <div id = 'apple'></div>
</div>
```

If your div is at the top of the document, your image would be outside of the window.